# Grass model with crossed planes is not shown # A-Frame

Tags: aframe

Engine A-Frame.

When I export a single plane of grass everything is ok. But the grass model with crossed planes is not shown.

Model format GLTF 2.0

Could you tell me what the problem can be with?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A-Frame has general suggestions for [troubleshooting models](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/models.html#troubleshooting). If you've tried that and still can't get it working, then there's probably no way to debug without sharing the model.. I'd suggest testing the model [here](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com). If it works there, file a bug on A-Frame. If not, file a bug on the viewer or exporter.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy

Thank you for reply!

Unfortunately, on the viewer the model is not shown. 

I use the following process for export:

1. Export from 3ds Max in Collada format.
2. Import to Blender and export in GLTF.

May it help you to dedug the problem? 

You can download the model in Collada and GLTF formats [here](https://yadi.sk/d/8Vef9-1Q3NCFe9)

Comment: The file doesn't work in A-Frame, three.js (which the viewer uses), or [BabylonJS](http://sandbox.babylonjs.com/), so I would assume the model is broken. You'll probably want to file a bug on the Blender exporter, including the files involved.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thank you so much for being attentive to my problem.